# Axios post request renders entire file contents as response instead of executing serverside file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, nodemailer

I am trying to send gmail using nodemmailer and axios in react application. But the response i get is the entire file contents. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Here is my frontend axios post request. THis request is working fine its returing 200 status code. The problem is with the response.

```
const axios = require('axios');
 axios({
            method: "POST", 
            url:"https://localhost/mail", 
            data: {
                recepients: recepients,   
                msgbody: msgbody,  
                msgsubject: msgsubject
            }
        }).then((response)=>{
            if (response.data.msg === 'success'){
                console.log("Message Sent."); 
               // this.resetForm()
            }else if(response.data.msg === 'fail'){
                console.log("Message failed to send.")
            }
        });
```

This is my mail.js file.

```
    const express = require('express')
    const app = express();
    var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

    var transport = {
      host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
      port: 587,
      domain:'gmail.com',
      secure:false,
      auth: {
        user: 'info@gmail.com',
        pass: 'password'
      }
    }

    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(transport)

    transporter.verify((error, success) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        console.log('Server is ready to take messages');
      }
    });


    app.post('/mail', (req, res, next) => {
      var name = "sender";
      var email = req.body.email;
      var message = req.body.message;

      var mail = {
        from: name,
        to: 'sender@gmail.com',  //Change to email address that you want to receive messages on
        subject: 'New Message from Contact Form',
        text: 'hi'
      }

      transporter.sendMail(mail, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          res.json({msg: 'fail'});
        } else {
          res.json({msg: 'success'});
        }
      }

)
});
```

This file does not get executed. This same file content i get as response. Anyone please help with this problem. Thanks in advance.

This is my app.js file.

/* application specific logic */

```
import 'jquery';
import 'jquery-contextmenu';
import 'jQuery-Impromptu';

import conference from './conference';
import API from './modules/API';
import keyboardshortcut from './modules/keyboardshortcut/keyboardshortcut';
import remoteControl from './modules/remotecontrol/RemoteControl';
import translation from './modules/translation/translation';
import UI from './modules/UI/UI';
import axios from 'axios';

window.APP = {
    API,
    conference,

    // Used by do_external_connect.js if we receive the attach data after
    // connect was already executed. status property can be 'initialized',
    // 'ready', or 'connecting'. We are interested in 'ready' status only which
    // means that connect was executed but we have to wait for the attach data.
    // In status 'ready' handler property will be set to a function that will
    // finish the connect process when the attach data or error is received.
    connect: {
        handler: null,
        status: 'initialized'
    },

    // Used for automated performance tests.
    connectionTimes: {
        'index.loaded': window.indexLoadedTime
    },

    keyboardshortcut,
    remoteControl,
    translation,
    UI
};

// TODO The execution of the mobile app starts from react/index.native.js.
// Similarly, the execution of the Web app should start from react/index.web.js
// for the sake of consistency and ease of understanding. Temporarily though
// because we are at the beginning of introducing React into the Web app, allow
// the execution of the Web app to start from app.js in order to reduce the
// complexity of the beginning step.
import './react'
```

;

Comment: You mean you are getting `mail.js` file as content in response ?

Comment: Also can you add content of 'app.js' file for us to see ? Thanks

Comment: yes i am getting mail.js content as response

Comment: Please edit the question and add content of 'app.js' file.

Comment: I have edited please check.

Comment: Where is the body-parser middleware for processing the post body? Also, did you setup your app to listen on port 443 with appropriate permissions? Can you add some console message inside the mail handler on your server to see what happens when the request arrives. and the body of the request?

Comment: actually this is open source project in github called "jitsi-meet". I have intalled that on server and trying to add nodemailer. sorry i dont have idea about body parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you have added `mail.js` file to public directory.

`app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))`

So what is happening is when ever you hit `https://localhost/mail` it is resolving any file matching in public and serving content.

Make sure you don't add it in public directory. or anyother directory which is used to add client side code.

Comment: So to which directory i have to add mail.js and what should i include in app.js

Comment: This is a sever side code it has to be on server side, 
Check any file which as `app.post(... blah blah)`  and add one more app.post('/mail') and add all your mail logic there.

Comment: If i dint find file containg app.post. is there any other work around. Can i use one more server to post this request.

Comment: I really don't know how you have structured your app and it is hard to guess. I would suggest you watch a tutorial on expressjs and it will be clear to you.
It will be very difficult to you also to understand this from questions .. It always helps to have understanding of the framework. and express is very simple framework.

Comment: I have frontend on one server and backend on another server. backend server is not accessible for me. If i have to add additional functionality can i use new server for that? only front end is accessible to me.

Comment: Yes.. you can create another server, just create another server and then add this route to your new sever.

Comment: Thank you . so for the trouble. but can you please provide link on how to setup node js on new server and how to redirect from my frontend. I am confused with ports.